# Is There a TypeScript IntelliSense Editor for OSX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellisense, typescript, sublimetext

Given that the TypeScript team is working on spreading the language around to the open-source community at large, it seems like creating a cross-platform solution for intellisense support would be high on their list:  Is this the case?  Does anyone know of any in-progress plugins for SublimeText et al. or developments directly from the TypeScript team that would bring similar support as what is offered in VisualStudio?

... And related:  Does anyone know if the TypeScript team is working on a more "friendly" public API for implementing intellisense or compilation?  Notable:  in terms of node support, there is no TypeScript.compile( str )-like method available, which makes integration far more complicated than it needs to be (see CoffeeScript for an example of a "friendly" API).

Any leads or information would be greatly appreciated.